# Citekey has changed between two instalation of Zotero

Tags: bibtex, zotero, better-bibtex

I am using Zotero with Latex, refering the documents to the exported library .bib file.
I have re-installed Zotero recently, and the citekey of the .bib file has changed.

Before citekeys were in this format:

```
NameTitleDate
```

And now it is this one:

```
Name_Title_Date
```

Furthermore, the "Title" entry is not exactly similar between the two.
I have tried different ways to export the library (Bibex, Better Bibex, BibLatex, BetterBiblatex) and match the former citekey, but it seems to always export in Name_Title_Date format.

Would anyone know how to get the exact same citekey format than before?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by not installing the Better BibTex package from Zotero. Once installed, all citations are back to the proper NameTitleDate format.

https://retorque.re/zotero-better-bibtex/installation/